# How to pass a @Published variable between classes using Combine?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I currently have an SDK that has a `@Published` boolean variable within a class (we can call this `ClassA`).

I'd like to expose this variable to an application (to use in SwiftUI), but not expose the entire `ClassA`. Therefore I have created a bridging class (`BridgingClass`) that will be exposed to the application without having to expose ClassA.

I have the following code. But it feels weird to use `sink` and manually change the variable based on the result.

```swift
@objc public class BridgingClass: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    var tmpVar: AnyCancellable?

    @objc public init (classA: ClassA) {
        super.init()

        tmpVar = classA.$hungryState.sink { val in
            self.isHungry = val
        }
    }

    @Published public var isHungry: Bool
}
```

How can I make the `isHungry` variable equal to `hungryState` from `classA`?

Comment: this isn't what Combine is designed for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you can use the [`assign(to:on:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/just/assign(to:on:)) method. This replaces the `sink` method used.

Basically the class would become:

```swift
@objc public class BridgingClass: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    private var cancallables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    @objc public init (classA: ClassA) {
        super.init()

        classA.$hungryState.assign(to: \.isHungry, on: self).store(in: &cancallables)
    }

    @Published public var isHungry: Bool
}
```